# Expected number of triples of friends

Tags: probability, expected-value, birthday

There are $n$ people are at a party. The probability that each pair of people is friends is $\frac{1}{2}$ (independent). Let $X$ be the number of triples of people that are friends. Find $E[X]$

For example, in the triple $X,Y,Z$,

$X$ is friends with $Y, Y$ is friends with $Z,$ and $X$ is friends with $Z$.

I think this is similar to the Birthday Paradox/Problem.

This is my approach, can someone tell me if I went wrong somewhere?

The total number of triples is $\binom{n}{3}$

Let $X_{i,j,k}$ be the random variable that is equal to $1$ when person $i$ is friends with person $j$, person $j$ is friends with person $k$ and person $i$ is friends with person $k$, and $0$ otherwise; where $1 \leq i < j < k \leq n$

I'm not sure if this is correct, but $E[X_{i,j,k}] = P(X_{i,j,k}) = (\frac{1}{2})^3$

$E[X]= \sum_{1 \leq i < j < k \leq n} E[X_{i,j,k}] = \frac{\binom{n}{3}}{2^3}$

Note that I'm not sure if $E[X_{i,j,k}] = P(X_{i,j,k}) = n(\frac{1}{2})^3$ because we need to sum over $n$ people

In that case, $E[X] = \frac{n \binom{n}{3}}{2^3}$

Comment: The additional $n$ is not needed.  The "summing over people" was already handled by the $\binom{n}{3}$.

Comment: I see, yes it does make sense that multiplying by n is not needed because $P(X_{i,j,k})$ is just finding the probability that a specific triple of people are friends. So I suppose $P(X_{i,j,k}) = (\frac{1}{2})^3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that any three selected people are mutual friends is $1/2^3$, due to the independence and identicallity of selection.   Let $X_{i,j,k}$ be the indicator function for this event, so the probability of the event is the expectation of the indicator, that is $\mathsf E(X_{i,j,k})$.

Thus the expected count of triples of mutual friends is the expectation of the sum of all indicators for selections of triples.

$$\mathsf E(X)=\sum_{1\leqslant i\lt j\lt k\leqslant n}\mathsf E(X_{i,j,k})=\binom n 3 \dfrac 1{2^3} = \dfrac{n!}{3!\,(n-3)!\, 2^3}$$

---

EG when $n=4$ then $\mathsf E(X)=\mathsf E(X_{1,2,3}+X_{1,2,4}+X_{1,3,4}+X_{2,3,4})=\tfrac 1{2}$